# Make my Vr app valid only in specifeid OCULUS

Tags: c#, oculus

Hello im trying to create a vr app valid in oculus quest 2 with unity c# , so i want when i sell my app , i sell with it the oculus that my app configured on it ?
i want to ask if there is a code dev solution to make my app installed only in a oculus sell it from me and my clients can't use it in other oculus .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.